# Discovering if Image File Exists Locally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my free time, I've been working on an HTML page that acts as an Ending screenshot tracker for Fire Emblem: Three Houses.  The way it works now is that, after the whole page has been loaded, I can click on one of the highlighted buttons and open a new page with that image.  While the program works as intended, it heavily relies on creating a new XMLHttpRequest() with the image's URL, sending said image so that the status can be checked (even when the file does not exist), and using the information to set the click attributes for over 6000 buttons.  Doing this, the default page lags for several seconds and my computer overhauls itself to load the page each time.  Is there a way to check if an image exists and, using that information, create an if/else statement without necessarily opening each file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: JavaScript is not permitted to access the File System directly, but you could set up an `error` event handler for an `img` element, which would trigger when the image doesn't load.